# Akka wait for Ack before stopping actor

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm using Plays `play.api.mvc.WebSocket`s in combination with `akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSub` events and this works fine already.

```
class SomeSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    val mediator = DistributedPubSubExtension(context.system).mediator
    mediator ! Subscribe("some_group", self)

    def receive: Actor.Receive = {
      case SubscribeAck(Subscribe("some_group", None, `self`)) =>
        context become ready
    }

    def ready: Actor.Receive = {
      // ...
    }

    override def postStop(): Unit = {
      mediator ! Unsubscribe("some_group", self)
    }
}
```

Once a socket gets close it sends `Unsubscribe`. Once the `Unsubscribe` is received by `DistributedPubSubMediator` it answers with `UnsubscribeAck`. However since at that moment (which is after `postStop`) the actor is stopped already and the `UnsubscribeAck` is moved Akkas dead letters mailbox and my log is spammed with something like:

> Message 
>   [akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSubMediator$UnsubscribeAck] from
>   Actor[akka://application/user/distributedPubSubMediator#261175455] to
>   Actor[akka://application/system/websockets/24/handler#325798268] was
>   not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be
>   turned off or adjusted with configuration settings
>   'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

I know I could just follow the advice in the log message, but that doesn't seem like good practice. Is there any way to tell the actor inside the `postStop` method to wait for the `UnsubscribeAck` before stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the `postStop` method, that is too late.

But instead of stopping before receiving the `UnsubscribeAck` you could just `become` waiting just for the `UnsubscribeAck` and stop when you receive it (or after some timeout, in case the `UnsubscribeAck` is never received.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that this would be good way to handle shutdown in general. However when using `play.api.mvc.WebSocket`, the actors gets created, managed and closed by the Play API and I can't influence the stopping of the actor. I hope there is still some other way to handle that, like telling Unsubscribe that there is no interest in an `UnsubscribeAck`.

Comment: In that case you can `watch` the actor. When it is stopped, the watcher will receive the `Terminated` message and can send the `Unsubscribe` instead of the `postStop` of the stopped actor. The watcher can then receive the `UnsubscribeAck`. Or, if you truly want just to ignore the `UnsubscribeAck`s, then let the stopped actor send the `Unsubscribe` with the `sender` set to its parent, so that the parent receives the `UnsubscribeAck`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually supposed to just work, as DistributedPubSubMediator watches for your actor to be `Terminated` when you subscribe. In a new project it does work as expected, and the mediator unsubscribes for you, so you may not need to do anything. I'm keeping this answer up as it doesn't do this in my project and it may be affecting other people.

What I'm doing is writing a second actor that is long-lived (you could create it in the controller), and have the WebSocket actor talk to that for managing subscriptions. This way the new actor can pass on unsubscribe messages, then it can receive and ignore the `UnsubscribeAck`.